# Avoid pop-ups in Excel while running code in Python

Tags: python, excel

I want to be able to open an Excel document and start manipulating the data without seeing any pop-ups.

I think the pop-ups are the ones stopping my Excel file from opening successfully. Here are the pop-ups I am seeing at excel and I would like to automatically answer them instead of doing it manually. I found some answers online but not for my case.

> The file format and extension of "xxx" don't match. The file could be
> corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do
> you want to open it anyway?
>
> option1: Yes , option2: No , option3: Help

or

> Open XML    Please select how you would like to open this file:
>
> - As an XML table
> - As a read-only workbook
> - use the XML Source task pane

or

> XML Import Error
>
> - ok
> - help

After I select: Yes & As an XML table & ok, everything works perfectly. If anyone could help me out I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. please add some code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: I have an algorithm running for downloading an excel file it's not so important. The part after that is the important one. Thank you.